# Installing Oracle in RHEL7 (IBM linuxone Community cloud)

Tags: oracle, installation, rhel7

I am trying to install oracle on the IBM linuxone community cloud: RHEL 7.

I have downloaded the oracle zip file using below link:
curl -jkL -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -o jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz

what must i do next to unzip and install the oracle in RHEL7?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial.

https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml

Donwload RPM and install.

Also you can try OpenJDK.

```
su -c "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk"
```

Comment: I couldn't use the yum command. I am getting the following error message. I couldn't register this machine as it is a free community server.                                                                                            "Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register."

Comment: Then unzip and declare JAVA_HOME variable.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin